# Generate pdf using byte array in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an API call which will return json as response.The json object contains pdfBytes and xml as string.How can I can the pdf bytes out of the response as blob and generate the document.

Below is my code snippet,here previously i was getting only one response from my API i.e only the pdf bytes and it was working as expected but now with json it is not working.

```
 var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var URLToPDF =
    "http://localhost:8080/downloadPDF";

  oReq.open("GET", URLToPDF, true);
  oReq.responseType = "blob";
  var that = this;
  oReq.onload = function() {
    console.log("Response received",oReq.response);
    const file = new Blob([oReq.response], { type: "application/pdf" });

    fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
 window.open(fileURL, "_blank");
    that.setState({ loaderFlagInvoicePdf: false });
    that.setState({ invoicePDFDisplay: true });
  };

  oReq.send();
```

Can anyone plaese suggest how can I get the blob out of the json response?

Comment: You need to change the type to {type : 'application/json'} or change the oReq.responseType to "json". Then get the byte text from the json

Comment: yes,i have done that changes but while exporting the pdf it is giving the error as "Unable to load PDF".Can you just help me to extract the pdf bytes as blob  from the JSON response which is not happening in this case

Comment: is the blob text in json base64-encoded? if yes, you need to decode it before using it  with new Blob()

Comment: No,I have decoded it using java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(new String(pdfData.getBytes(),the problem i am facing is not able to extract the pdfBytes from JSON and convert it to PDF